# Stata installation: how to add stata to the .profile PATH?

Tags: bash, .profile

I am completely new to Linux and have no idea what to do.
What I am trying to do is the following: I want to install Stata 16 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 64-bit. 
I followed the stata installation guide and till now it worked out fine. Now I am asked to do this:

> If you use bash , sh , or ksh , there is a line in your .profile (in
>   your home directory) that looks like
>
> PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin"
>
> Edit the file and add /usr/local/stata to the list:
>
> PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/local/stata"

My problem is: There is not line in my .profile that looks like the one above. My .profile says:

> ## if running bash if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
>
> ```
> # include .bashrc if it exists
> if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then   . "$HOME/.bashrc"
> fi fi
> ```
>
> ## set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
>
> ```
> PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" fi
> ```
>
> ## set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
>
> ```
> PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" fi
> ```

The only files in my home directory are .bash_history, .bash_logout, .bashrc, .profile and .sudo_as_admin_successful.

What do I have to do in order to include stata into the PATH? 
Could someone please be so incredibly kind and walk me through the steps?

Side problem: my keyboard has some errors. It cannot write any signs that need the AltGr-key anymore.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Have You already installed Stata and just want to update the PATH ? Check the file `.bashrc` - there should be a PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similar to add my scripts to my path by adding this to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/scripts
```

So, to add **stata** to your path, add this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/stata
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!